# New Twisted Treeline Base Walls - Skills or Spells that jump over them

Tags: league-of-legends

**Intro:**
With the new twisted treeline riot also introduced this new elevated base which has one set of stairs on each side and a big wide wall in the middle. The reason behind this design (in my oppinion) is to solve the problem of Turtling (i.e. Staying back and defending most of the time without risking going out and fight). In the old map it was really easy to turtle because the distance between the last turret and the base/shop was really small so practically if you had a good defensive team you could stay safe and healed all the time and protect your mid turret whereas attackers would eventually get worn down and have to back down or overcommit and die.

With this new wall between your turret and your base you can't do that anymore.

They also introduced that new even wider wall seperating your nexus from the outter jungle.
The reason behind this is that people would easily flash in there (or spin or jump etc) and storm your unprotected nexus after they had destroyed your last turret.

**My Question:** 
Which skills or spells can jump over each of those walls?
I'm pretty sure that for the first one most of the classic jumping spells would do.
But the second one is really big. So if you guys have tested it out put your results out there. :)

Comment: I haven't tested it, but Kha'zix with the evo upgrade should be able to do it if anyone can.

Comment: Not tested, but Jarvan usually can jump wide walls with his flag + spear combo.

Comment: @Mechko Yeah I know all those. Tristana can jump pretty far too. I doubt any of them can jump over that big wall though...Will test it myself whenever I can. I was hoping we can gather a nice list with all those that can and can't. Being able to jump over THAT wall would give a tremendous advantage to that champion.

Comment: @PedroJack Jarvan has some of the best wall-jumping range, I play treeline all the time and he's the most godly of wall-jumping before lee sin.

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos I don't think any champions can jump over the fattest part of that wall in the middle, but a few others can jump over the wall closer to the sides without getting in range of the tower. If you ever want to test wall-jumps Jarvan is the best because he can jump a wall as long as he can reach his flag on the other side. Testing his jump distance is as easy as looking and the range indicator and your E, meaning you don't have to use mana and wait for cooldowns.

Comment: @SadlyNot Yeah I will check and get back at you guys! Thx for the advice on Jarvan he's actually one of my mains. I will start with him. I just always thought that there are champs with skills that jump further away or so it feels like...For example an upgraded jump by Khazix like Mechko said.

Comment: I'm looking for a scaled map to make the calculations and answer your question, but I don't have any luck finding one.

Answer (score 1):

The wall was made thick enough so that you couldn't just flash or 'jump' over/through the wall and quickly end the game (Master Yi, Jax, Trynd, etc. ), so I wouldn't be surprised if very few ,if any champs at all, could make it over the wall.

I've heard that Kha'zix evolved leap can make it over as well as Elise as long as an enemy is on the other side. I've also heard that if you're lucky Shaco's Decieve can make it over the wall as well with practice. Jarvan's may be possible but haven't seen someone post about trying it.